# Installing BlueZ 5.50 doesn't update bluetoothd

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to install BlueZ 5.50 on Ubuntu 16.04 because I need MIDI support.

I compiled and installed it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
sudo apt-get install libical-dev
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
cd bluez-5.50
./configure --enable-midi
make -j8
sudo make install
```

The problem is that it doesn't update `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd`, which is the default version that is started when I reboot.
`bluetoothd -v` results in `5.37`
but `./src/bluetoothd -v` results in `5.50`.

The only version in the path seems to be the old version:

```
whereis bluetoothd
bluetoothd: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd /usr/share/man/man8/bluetoothd.8.gz
```

Why does the install script keep the old version? How can I update everything to the new version? Do I have to?

Right now, MIDI BLE seems to be working, even with the old version of bluetoothd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile a programm from sources and do not use pre-compiled dpkg packages, the dpkg packages will not be touched or changed in any way.

Normally, the `configure` step instructs the build to use */usr/local* as install prefix, instead of */usr*. This is to prevent self-compiled stuff to override binaries or other files that are shipped within a dpkg package.
So you `bluetoothd` binary resides somewhere in */usr/local*.

```
root@localhost:~/bluez-5.50# find /usr/local -name bluetoothd
/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Unfortunately or luckily, not really sure, the `make install` does place a `systemd` service and target in */lib/systemd/system*, which overrides the files from the dpkg package `bluez`.
In my opinion, these two files should go into `/etc/systemd/system` to prevent e.g. an update of `bluez` overwriting your manually installed version. To make that, you also should add `--with-systemdsystemunitdir=/etc/systemd/system` to your `configure` command and reinstall the new bluez and the old bluez.

```
root@localhost:~/bluez-5.50# ./configure --enable-midi --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/etc/systemd/system
root@localhost:~/bluez-5.50# make 
root@localhost:~/bluez-5.50# make install
root@localhost:~/bluez-5.50# apt-get install --reinstal bluez
```